# What's wrong with this img src and a href code?

Tags: php, html

What's wrong with this :

```
echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Haddad-Guest-House/193701947328195" target="_blank">'<img src="http://imgit.me/i/6G0R4D9.png"></a>';
```

Comment: The apostrophe right before `<img`... If your IDE is not able to inform you of this syntax error, consider switching to a better IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single quote between the `<a>` and the `<img>` node that you should remove. Try like this:

```
echo '<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Haddad-Guest-House/193701947328195" target="_blank"><img src="http://imgit.me/i/6G0R4D9.png"></a>';
```

Comment: Thanks.
How do I also change the weight and height of the image ? forgot all HTML basics. /facepalm

Comment: @wadie, you could add the `style` attribute on the img tag: `style="width: 100px; height: 100px"`.